# 2 Way messaging system in C# using Sockets

Tags: c#, sockets, chat

I am trying to make a 2 Way chat messaging system, One that would send a message and the other party gets it and sends back a message and the other party can reply as well. I found a code I have been able to utilize to make mine and it works fine but it's only a one-way message system hence I wanted something that the client can send a message to the server and the server back to the client.

My code looks like this, tho it's a one-way

**Server**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Threading;
using System.IO;

namespace Sever
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            TcpListener serverSocket = new TcpListener(4523);
            serverSocket.Start();
            Console.WriteLine("Started!");
            while (true)
            {
                TcpClient clientSocket = serverSocket.AcceptTcpClient();
                handleClient clientx = new handleClient();
                clientx.startClient(clientSocket);
            }
        }
    }

    public class handleClient
    {
        TcpClient clientSocket;
        public void startClient(TcpClient inClientSocket)
        {
            this.clientSocket = inClientSocket;
            Thread ctThread = new Thread(Chat);
            Thread xthread = new Thread(msg);
            ctThread.Start();
        }

        private void Chat()
        {
            byte[] buffer = new byte[100];
            while (true)
            {
                NetworkStream ns = clientSocket.GetStream();
                BinaryReader reader = new BinaryReader(clientSocket.GetStream());
                Console.WriteLine(reader.ReadString());
            }
        }

        private void msg()
        {
            byte[] buf2 = new byte[100];
            while (true)
            {
                TcpClient client = new TcpClient("localhost", 4523);
                NetworkStream ns = client.GetStream();
                string str = Console.ReadLine();
                BinaryWriter bw = new BinaryWriter(client.GetStream());
                bw.Write(str);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now this is the Client.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        while (true)
        {
            TcpClient client = new TcpClient("localhost",4523);
            NetworkStream ns = client.GetStream();
            byte[] buffer = new byte[100];
            string str = Console.ReadLine();
            BinaryWriter bw = new BinaryWriter(client.GetStream());
            bw.Write(str);
        }
    }
}
```

What am I Really Missing, Client remains the same?

Comment: You need two threads / tasks in your programs: On that continously receives chat messages, and the other which asks for user input and sends the chat message. A sender and receiver thread. Look into `System.Threading.Tasks`

Comment: You can just receive messages on the other thread while sending messages on demand. And remember to `Close()` and `Dispose()` your streams after you end using them.

Comment: @m.rogalski was thinking of using the same Binary Writer as well in the **server**, works that way??

Comment: No, It won't work that way. You have to use each writer for each stream, but close the connections and streams as you end using them.

Comment: @m.rogalski I have editted the code maybe you pls show me programmatically.. very new to this...

Answer (score 0):

Ok i finally resolved it , its now a 2 way chat, did it with streamwriter and reader at the same time.. works like a charm

**server**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Threading;
using System.IO;

namespace Sever
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            TcpListener serverSocket = new TcpListener(4523);
            serverSocket.Start();
            Console.WriteLine("Started!");
            while (true)
            {
                TcpClient clientSocket = serverSocket.AcceptTcpClient();
                handleClient clientx = new handleClient();
                clientx.startClient(clientSocket);
            }
        }
    }

    public class handleClient
    {
        TcpClient clientSocket;
        public void startClient(TcpClient inClientSocket)
        {
            this.clientSocket = inClientSocket;
            Thread ctThread = new Thread(Chat);
            ctThread.Start();
        }

        private void Chat()
        {
            byte[] buffer = new byte[100];
            while (true)
            {
                NetworkStream ns = clientSocket.GetStream();
                BinaryReader reader = new BinaryReader(clientSocket.GetStream());
                Console.WriteLine(reader.ReadString());

                BinaryWriter bw = new BinaryWriter(clientSocket.GetStream());
                string str = Console.ReadLine();
                bw.Write(str);
            }
        }
     }
}
```

**Client**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.IO;

namespace Client
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            while (true)
            {
                TcpClient client = new TcpClient("localhost",4523);
                NetworkStream ns = client.GetStream();
                byte[] buffer = new byte[100];
                string str = Console.ReadLine();
                BinaryWriter bw = new BinaryWriter(client.GetStream());
                bw.Write(str);

                BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(client.GetStream());
                Console.WriteLine(br.ReadString());
            }
        }
    }
}
```